# How to get key filtered by its value in multidimensional array Python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I got this data

```
employee_detail_list = {
      'John Doe': {
          'name': 'EMP-0001',
          'first_name': 'John',
          'last_name': 'Doe',
          'full_name': 'John Doe',
          'company': 'Company 1'
      },
      'Tom Smith': {
          'name': 'EMP-0002',
          'first_name': 'Tom',
          'last_name': 'Smith',
          'full_name': 'Tom Smith',
          'company': 'Company 2'
      },
      'Andrew Sebastian': {
          'name': 'EMP-0003',
          'first_name': 'Andrew',
          'last_name': 'Sebastian',
          'full_name': 'Andrew Sebastian',
          'company': 'Company 2'
      },   }
```

i want output

```
Tom Smith
Andrew Sebastian
```

by filtering value *"Company 2"*, i've try this code:

```
# list out keys and values separately
key_list = list(employee_detail_list.keys())
val_list = list(employee_detail_list.values())

# print key with val Company 2
position = val_list.index("Company 2")
print(key_list[position])
```

but always ended up with this error:

```
ValueError: 'Company 2' is not in list
```

any thought what is wrong? thanks before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does what you need. `.items()` returns data as iterable objects that can be traversed.

```
for key, value in employee_detail_list.items():
    if value["company"] == "Company 2":
        print(key)

# Output
Tom Smith
Andrew Sebastian
```

The problem with your solution is that `val_list = list(employee_detail_list.values())` returns a list with objects and you are trying to find `val_list.index("Company 2")` by string which is not there

Comment: @FahmiSabilaDinnulhaq if I answered your question, don't forget to mark it as correct)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()`

```py
employee_detail_list = {
      'John Doe': {
          'name': 'EMP-0001',
          'first_name': 'John',
          'last_name': 'Doe',
          'full_name': 'John Doe',
          'company': 'Company 1'
      },
      'Tom Smith': {
          'name': 'EMP-0002',
          'first_name': 'Tom',
          'last_name': 'Smith',
          'full_name': 'Tom Smith',
          'company': 'Company 2'
      },
      'Andrew Sebastian': {
          'name': 'EMP-0003',
          'first_name': 'Andrew',
          'last_name': 'Sebastian',
          'full_name': 'Andrew Sebastian',
          'company': 'Company 2'
      }
}

def isFromCompany2(data):
    return data["company"] == "Company 2"

result = filter(isFromCompany2, employee_detail_list.values())

print(list(result))
```

This is a nice article that explains it https://realpython.com/python-filter-function/